# openpyxl cell style not reporting correctly

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

Using the python library **openpyxl** I am reading an XLSX file created in excel 2007. it is empty apart from cell A1 which is coloured yellow and has the value "test" written in it. I can easily retrieve the value from that cell, however when I attempt to determine the fill colour I get the following results:

```
this_sheet.cell("A1").style.fill.start_color
```

returns "FFFFFF"

```
this_sheet.cell("A1").style.fill.end_color
```

returns "FF0000"

Testing this on other blank cells I get exactly the same results, and trying to retrieve the font style information keeps returning calibri size 11 (our system default).

Am I going about this all wrong?  Is there an alternative method i should be using?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: .xlsx is an xml format so I have added that tag; may draw the attention of people with relevant experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openpyxl is still in development, and styles are not yet completely implemented, thus you can encounter some issues here and there. Don't hesitate to open an issue on the [project bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issues/) if you want.

Comment: I figured that might be the case as it does seem to be grabbing system defaults.