# how to read the xlsx color infomation by using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read excel file.

For my application, i need to read the background color of the cell in the xlsx file
But i cant find how to load those color info.

I tried to use cell.style.fill.color.index, but it only return FFFFFFFF as background which is not correct to the file i read.

Does openpyxl support reading color format?

Comment: Did you mean `start_color` instead of `color`?  I don't believe that the Fill object has a color attribute.

Comment: The author of openpyxl, [responded to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560675/openpyxl-cell-style-not-reporting-correctly?rq=1), back in April.  Quote:  "Openpyxl is still in development, and styles are not yet completely implemented, thus you can encounter some issues here and there."

Answer (score 8):

### UPDATE (2014):

I updated [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) to v. 2.2.  They seem to have resolved the problem that I documented in my original answer (see below).  I am now able to successfully retrieve the background color after I've set it manually through Excel.  However, the syntax has changed slightly:

```
somecell.fill.start_color.index
```

### ORIGINAL RESPONSE (2012):

I experimented with this and noticed that if I set the background color via openpyxl like this:

```
_cell.style.fill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID
_cell.style.fill.start_color.index = Color.DARKGREEN
```

then retrieve the value like this:

```
_style.fill.start_color.index
```

then I get the correct response:

```
'FF008000'
```

However, if I set the background color in Excel and save the file, then access it via openpyxl, then I get the same thing you did:

```
'FFFFFFFF'
```

So, the upshot seems to be that opepyxl styles are still unreliable.  See my comment, under the question, with a link to the comment from the author of openpyxl.

Comment: Just ignore the style and access the fill directly `_cell.fill.start_color = DARKGREEN`. If you are still having problems. Please submit a bug.