# Modify values of an Excel file without changing the color formatting

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

In a Excel file,
I want to replace all fields containing `-0.01` by `NR`.

In this file, all the boxes containing `0.01` are yellow. **I want to keep this color formatting.**

But, when I replace the values as I want, all the colors are removed from the file.

Here is my code

```
# Clean the spreadsheet
def cleanSpreadSheet(self):
    for sheet in self.data:
        dataSheet = self.data[sheet]
        for line in dataSheet:
            for index, entry in enumerate(line):
                if entry == -0.01:
                    line[index] = 'NR'

    pyexcel_xlsx.save_data(self.nameFile, self.data)
```

Comment: I believe pyexcel_xlsx doesn't support Fonts, Charts, Colors, as stated in their ReadMe file on github, https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx  If you want to retain the color info, you could use `xlwt` package, set the cells to required custom color and write your data

Comment: Yes but what about that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12043973/1670830

Comment: In the code you have mentioned `pyexcel_xlsx`. are you ok to use other packages aswell?

Comment: Yes! I only need to read the file, pu it in some custom Classes and replace `-0.01` by `NR`. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some conditonal formatting enabled that applies only to certain interval of numbers?

Comment: Here is the file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/76042fadde4c57713367292618f377f520180628141704/fe1168

Comment: Not false @pnuts... But I am looking for an automated process via Python.