# How to read information about excell cell background using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read the background color of the cell in the excel sheet. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043973/how-to-read-the-xlsx-color-infomation-by-using-openpyxl

Answer (score 1):

make sure your file .xlsx file is in the same directory of your .py file. Apparently the openpyxl's color system seems a bit off.

```
import openpyxl

excel_file = 'your_file.xlsx' 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file, data_only=True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
# this gives you hexadecimal value of the color
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index
```