# Python: openpyxl how to read a cell font color

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried to print `some_cell.font.color.rgb` and got various results.

For some I got what I want (like "`FF000000`"), but for others it gives me `Value must be type 'basetring'`. I assume that the latter is because I haven't actually defined the font color for these cells.

I'm using openpyxl 2.2.2

Comment: What do you expect for cells where you haven't set the font color?

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace when it complains `Value must be type 'basestring'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is a bug in openpyxl and I think you should report it [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues).

Debugging the following code (with [trepan3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k) of course):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
c = ws['A4']  # cell gets created here
print(ws['A4'].font.color)
```

I get:

```
Color(rgb=Value must be type 'str', indexed=Value must be type 'int', auto=Value must be type 'bool', theme=1, tint=0.0, type='theme')
```

and this is coming from *_repr_()* of class *Typed()* in file `openpyxl/descriptors/base.py`. This message is given when a value hasn't been initialized. Notice that "indexed" and "auto" also haven't been set.

But these presumably should have been set when the code for the access of `ws['a4']` was performed.

*Note: the slight difference in message: 'str' instead of 'basestring' is probably attributable to the fact that I was using Python 3 or less likely openpyxl 2.2.3*

And if there's some other additional code should that I should have added in my example, then at least https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html should indicate that.

See also [openpyxl cell style not reporting correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560675/openpyxl-cell-style-not-reporting-correctly?rq=1) where one of the developers seems to say the same thing in so many words.

**Edit**:

A couple of other things may be of interest to note. First, you can *set* a value and then read it, for example you can do this:

```
c.font.color.rgb = "FF000000"
```

Second, if you test `c.font.color.rgb` in a boolean it will look like a value has been set. That is

```
if c.font.color: print("yes")
```

will print "yes".

Answer (score 2):

I did a check in this way:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
c = ws['A1']
if 'rgb' in c.font.color.__dict__:
    print(c.font.color.rgb)
else:
    print('None')
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember diving into the openpyxl source a while back to try and whittle down some styling issues.  If you are opening a pre-existing excel file, cells will only be styled if they contain content.  For example, if you have a .xlsx with A:A being highlighted yellow, but only A1 contains any text, then openpyxl will not have that highlighting info available for A2.  And if (using openpyxl) you record some data to A2 then it will initiate that cell with no styling, and you'd end up with your A column being yellow everywhere except A2.

The difficulty I ran into was in monkey-patching the cell creation to determine if the sheet has styling that should be maintained on an inheritance basis.  If you have A:A styled with thick border, and B:B styled with thin border, which do you inherit from?

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative solution, is to test the types of `cell.color` and `cell.color.rgb`.

The following test seems to give cells which their colors set:

```
if cl.font.color != None and type(cl.font.color.rgb) == str:
   # where cl =  cell of interest
   rbg = cl.font.color.rgb
```

It seems `cell.font.color` is `None` when style is used and `type(cell.color.rgb)` is `<class 'openpyxl.styles.colors.RGB'>` when no color is set.

Note: This solution has not been tested thoroughly and may not work for all cases.